# In PHP is it possible to get the last curl attempt's syntax as a string?

Tags: php, linux, curl

Occasionally I would like to debug a curl request by running the actual curl command in a Linux Terminal  Is it possible to get the command generated by PHP in a String format to get the curl command, something like this?

```
curl -X PUT \
-H "x-pushbots-appid: 54cc0a511d0ab13c0528b459d" \
-H "x-pushbots-secret: 1444fe8be3324ff7128f25aa18cdee12" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{ "token" : String ,  "platform" : String ,  "lat" : String ,  "lng" : String ,  "active" : Array ,  "tag" : Array ,  "alias" : String  }' \
https://api.pushbots.com/deviceToken
```

Comment: PHP uses the libcurl library, not the curl executable..  The CLI has its own syntax.  You can convert it I'm sure, but why not just debug using your PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid CLI execution as it is extremely hard to debug it. I recommend you make use of PHP's cURL extension (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) and then you can debug using:

1. Try-Catch (Exception handling)
2. error_get_last()
3. function() OR die("---log / break code --");